# React Material-UI TextField looses focus with every key

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a **material-ui** CharField, but I am unable to type a full string because it looses focus after one key entered, so I have to click on it after every key stroke, which is not acceptable.

This is my component `SearchControl`:

```
render() {
    const SearchControl = () => {
      return (
        <div className="col-6">
          <TextField
            className="col-11"
            id={this.state.code}
            defaultValue={this.state.code}
            label={"Modelo o Número de Serie"}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <IconButton
            ariaLabel="Buscar"
            className="col-1"
            onClick={this.handleSearchProductClick}
          >
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      );
    };

    if (!this.state.messageShown) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <NavBar onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div fullWidth style={{ display: "flex", paddingTop: "30px" }}>
            <SearchControl />
            <ShortcutButtons />
          </div>
          <div fullWidth>
            <ProductsTable />
          </div>
          <div fullWidth />
          <div fullWidth style={{ display: "flex", paddingTop: "10px" }}>
            <ControlButtons />
            <TotalsDisplay />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try giving id a non-state value.

Comment: I had this before, you're parent is remounting on change. you need to make sure you don't rerender a parent component.

Comment: To test this add a console.log on your `componentDidMount`this should show the component remounting each time

Comment: @SirajAlam It didn't work.

Comment: Try passing the value prop as the current value being stored in the state.

Comment: You're passing the value into the defaultValue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was that `SearchControl` component was an arrow function, which implies that it was a brand new function each rendering and, hence, a brand new component each rendering.

I changed `SearchControl` component declaration to a regular function, so each rendering would refer to the same function and, hence, to the same component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.SearchControl = this.SearchControl.bind(this);
}

SearchControl() {
      return (
        <div className="col-6">
          <TextField
            className="col-11"
            id={this.state.code}
            defaultValue={this.state.code}
            label={"Modelo o Número de Serie"}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <IconButton
            ariaLabel="Buscar"
            className="col-1"
            onClick={this.handleSearchProductClick}
          >
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      );
    }

render() {
   if (!this.state.messageShown) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <NavBar onUpdate={this.onUpdate} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div fullWidth style={{ display: "flex", paddingTop: "30px" }}>
            <this.SearchControl />
            <ShortcutButtons />
          </div>
          <div fullWidth>
            <ProductsTable />
          </div>
          <div fullWidth />
          <div fullWidth style={{ display: "flex", paddingTop: "10px" }}>
            <ControlButtons />
            <TotalsDisplay />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Here is a related answer (different symptoms, but similar root cause): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210288/popover-menu-renders-in-different-place-than-the-anchor-element/60211641#60211641.