# Transition of Accordion in material ui gone after "controlling" the Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, transition, accordion

I am using the example of controlled Accordions from material ui's docs (https://material-ui.com/components/accordion/#ControlledAccordions.js) but after adding onChange and extended props to the Accordion component, it's transitions are gone.
Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lueeq
The transitions are fine after removing onChange and extended props from Accordion in Acc.js (line 77, 78)

Comment: Same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210288/popover-menu-renders-in-different-place-than-the-anchor-element/60211641#60211641. You're defining MuiAccordion nested within the History component. Every time History is re-rendered, MuiAccordion will be re-mounted. You need to move MuiAccordion to the top-level.

Comment: @RyanCogswell makes sense! Thanks, will do that!

Comment: @YashKandalkar did you suss this out? thx

Comment: @sambomartin yes, just don't define any components inside another component, define them at the top level as Ryan said. That worked for me.